# How to call a python program from a perl cgi script

Tags: python, perl, cgi, cgi-bin

I'm new to python..
wanted to know , how to call a python program with arguments from the cgi script.
And also retrieve the return value from the python prog.

I tried this.. but didnt work...

```
    my $bin = "/var/www/pythonprog.py";
    my @args = ($name1,$pass1);
    my $cmd = "$bin ".join(" ", @args);
    $cmd =~ tr///;
    system ($cmd);
```

Comment: Looks like a perl question?  Make sure you have the proper hashbang in the python file and proper permissions set.

Comment: The system command takes a list, where the first value is the path to the executable, and each value after that are the command line arguments. If you are new to perl, check out the perldoc here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: Out of curiosity, what did you expect `$cmd =~ tr///;` to do?

Comment: The command should work, unless a) your python script is not executable for some reason (lack of/bad shebang, file permission), b) `$name1,$pass1` contains shell meta characters or whitespace. The only way to figure out what is wrong is if you elaborate on "it didnt work". For example by supplying error messages.

Comment: Why not simply write your CGI script in Python and avoid perl entirely?

Answer (score 0):

System wants a list argument.
Try this:

```
my $bin = "/var/www/pythonprog.py";
my @cmd = ($bin,$name1,$pass1);
system (@cmd);
```

EDIT: looks like you have a taint problem, see the great comments below.

Comment: No ... there's still an error....

Software error:

Insecure $ENV{PATH} while running with -T switch at /usr/lib/cgi-bin/new.cgi line 23.

For help, please send mail to the webmaster (webmaster@localhost), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Comment: @JayanthSilesh The `-T` (taint) security switch lets you know that your path has not been properly de-tainted. You can solve it by setting your path, e.g. `$ENV{PATH} = ""`, with the result that you then have to use the full path for any system calls, e.g. `system("/bin/echo foo")`.

Comment: `system` can use a single scalar too.

Comment: No.. nothing is helping.///
Basically i'm running a html page..
which when the submit button is clicked... it calls a cgi prog...
from the cgi prog , i want to call a python prog ...
So this is the part i'm stuck...

I'm not ablr to call a python script from the cgi script...